# I want to delete Ubuntu from the Partition on my Mac, but I cannot access my Mac OS system

Tags: installation, partitioning, mac

I made a partition on my iMac to install Ubuntu, which I did by DVD. I've been using it for a while but, I wanted to switch over to my Mac OS and When I restart my comp and hold down the "alt" button a purple screen comes up and gives me the option of picking Ubuntu or Mac OS using the arrow keys on my keyboard, but they won't move up or down for me and after 10 seconds it goes into Ubuntu.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can always boot into your OS X partition, by inserting the OS X Installation-Disk first and then holding down <kbd>C</kbd> during startup.

This way you are able to delete the unwanted partition, in this case Ubuntu within Disk-Utility, in order to then have OS X left as first boot-partition.

Here is a link to [Startup key combinations for Intel-based Macs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533)

Another Option is to download either `grub customizer` or `StartUp-Manager` from Ubuntu Software Center to chose your default OS from.

Comment: I have tried your second option, but I can't get it to work. First option is a no go, because I never received a disk with my iMac. Is there anyway that I could do a hard reboot and get just the Mac OS system back? I backed everything up on an external HD, in case something like this happened.

Comment: What exactly did not work with the second option?! Did you downloaded one of the two programs suggested and changed the boot order and that didn't succeed (booting up OS X as default)?!

Answer (score 0):

You can access Mac OS X by simply holding Alt key while booting your computer and then selecting the drive you want to boot from. Then, when you are inside mac you can install rEFIt. This will allow you to select the OS you want to boot from every time you start your computer.